# AWS DynamoDB: Transformar dados com DynamoDB.Update

Tags: amazon-aws

Gostaria de saber se alguém mais teve necessidade de realizar uma alteração nos dados gravados numa tabela DynamoDB da AWS onde é necessário utilizar os dados originais gravados e altera-los.

Exemplo:

Tenho gravado em uma tabela:

```js
{
    "Name": {
        "S": "John Doe"
    }
}
```

após o processo precisa ficar:

```js
{
    "Name": {
        "S": "John"
    }
}
```

O que faço hoje é um `Get` (para pegar a informação), processo os dados e em seguida um `Update` para salvar.

Sei que o `Update` já faz a leitura e pode transformar elementos da tabela com o `SET`, no entanto, não cheguei a conclusão se dentro de `SET` é possível pegar a informação existente no banco e processá-la dentro do próprio comando.

Answer (score 2):

Tudo bem?

Você provavelmente já resolveu isso Eldad Hauzman, pois esse post é de 4 meses atrás, mas para quem está vindo com essa dúvida agora pode se beneficiar. Por isso vou tentar responder.

Sou meio novato também, mas acho que já consigo ajudar com isso.

**Importante**

```
 1 - A sua tabela deve ter uma chave de partição pelo menos, senão vc não consegue criá-la.
 2 - Não é obrigatório ter atributos adicionais, lembre-se que é um DB orientado a documentos, então só a chave é suficiente para trabalhar com o documento.
 3- Se 'Name' é a chave de particionamento da sua tabela não há como vc alterá-la.
```

Então, se você tem uma chave, por exemplo, o 'email' da pessoa e um atributo 'Name', você consegue fazer tudo pelo update_item em uma única operação.

**EXEMPLO:**

```
import boto3

def botoConfig():
    my_config = Config(
        region_name='sa-east-1',
        signature_version='v4',
        retries={
            'max_attempts': 10,
            'mode': 'standard'
        }
    )
    return my_config

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', config=botoConfig())
pessoas= dynamodb.Table('pessoas')


def update_name(v_email, v_new_name):
    pessoas.update_item(
        Key={
            'email': v_email,
        },
        UpdateExpression='SET Name= :nm',
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':nm': v__new_name,
        }
    )
```

Espero ter ajudado!
Abraço